# Android, getting back to the same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a levels.java file where the user can pick one of 3 levels, then when his choice is made I run this code:

```
startActivityForResult (new Intent(this, GameScreen.class),requestCode);
```

which displays the user the "game screen" where he can play for a while, the game is a simple timer game (as I am a noob learning Android) and has a pause function if the user wants to take a break.
I also call the pause function if the user hits the back button on the phone.

My problem is, when the user hits the pause function, does whatever he wants to do then comes back to my app, it shows him the levels.java screen and when he selects to go back into the game it starts a new gamescreen, it does not go back to the paused screen :(

Which means any points etc he may have made is gone.

How do I go back to the *same* screen that he was on before?

In other words:
If old activity is still running return to it, if not start a new activity. But... how?

Thanks!
R

EDIT: The code I run if the user clicks the pause button:

```
if (r_settings.getPausedValue() == false) {
        ib7.setClickable(false);
        ib2.setClickable(false);
        ib1.setClickable(false);
        r_settings.setPausedValue(true);
        main_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.game_paused);
```

Basically, check if the game is already paused, if not, disable buttons, set paused value to true, show a graphic that says "Game paused" in the middle of the screen.

Comment: are you saving SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes, I am... I'm a noob so mind telling me what does that have to do with my problem?

Comment: I just wanted to verify.  You are retrieving them in onResume()?

Comment: Nope, I only use SP when gameover() to save which level he has achieved and in what time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameScreen.class);
> intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
> startActivityForResult (intent,requestCode);
> ```

Comment: hm... well hitting the back button finishes the activity. are you overwriting onBackPressed? And if the user hits pause - what are you doing? If the activity is actually still running this should work.

Comment: Edited the code on top, please check.
Nope, am not overriding "onBackPressed"... The activity is still running because if I do not pause it, the is sound coming from the activity even though its in the background (was quite irritating at first till I fixed it.)

Comment: hm that's strange. can you make sure onDestroy() is not being called? just add a log into onDestroy(). The standard behavior for the back button finishes the activity. Or are you doing something in onStart that could cause the game to start again?

Comment: Ok, I have not overridden onStart. In onDestroy I added this code: Toast.makeText(this, "Exiting...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); but that does not get called.

Comment: Ok.. then try changing your launchMode to singleTop for your GameScreen activity (android:launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest)

Comment: ok, did it: http://pastebin.com/q260eaKZ unfortunately, still no joy... it starts from the beginning (i know this because i have a counter that goes 3... 2... 1... on every start)